# How to get featured post title & image using JSON API?

Tags: post-thumbnails, api, json, featured-post

Is there any possibility to get featured post title and image using the [JSON API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/).

I tried using this:

```
example.com/?json=the_post_thumbnails&count=3
```

But instead of recent posts, I get featured posts.

Comment: Hello warzone_fz - welcome to the WordPress Development community! Questions regarding 3rd-party plugins and themes are considered off-topic for our community as it's rare that many if any members of our community has experience with such items - as such these questions tend to remain unanswered. Your question would be best asked in the official support channels for your plugin(s). Please read the [on-topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [ask] sections of our [help] for more information regarding what questions are a good fit for our community.

Comment: @boscho As this plugin is "future core", we (moderators) have (discussed and) decided that this plugin is on topic.

Comment: @kaiser This question is related to another JSON API plugin, not the one slated for inclusion with WP core. It is related to: http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/

Comment: @RachelBaker Oh. Thanks! The OP will have to change the plugin to keep it on topic then.

Answer (score 0):

I made a shortcut to my image by adding it directly to the API response.

---

```
//Add in functions.php, this hook is for  my 'regions' post type
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'create_api_posts_meta_field' );

function create_api_posts_meta_field() {
  register_rest_field( 'regions', 'group', array(
         'get_callback'    => 'get_post_meta_for_api',
         'schema'          => null,
      )
  );
}
```

---

```
//Use the post ID to query the image and add it to your payload. 


function get_post_meta_for_api( $object ) {
  $post_id = $object['id'];
  $post_meta = get_post_meta( $post_id );
  $post_image = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id );      
  $post_meta["group_image"] = wp_get_attachment_image_src($post_image)[0];


  //var_dump(wp_get_attachment_image($post_image)); die();
  //Different image codex return different values, narrow in on what you want

  return $post_meta;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Tty this one

```
jQuery.getJSON('/latest-post-as-json/', function(data) {

    jQuery('#externalBlock').append('<h1>'+data.post_title+'</h1>');

    jQuery('#externalBlock').append(data.post_content);



//etc

});
```

Comment: Please add a proper explanation to your code